# AppAuth Authentication

Tags: android, appauth

I want to use [AppAuth](https://openid.github.io/AppAuth-Android/) for my Android application.

But as per there documentation, they mention that "WebView is explicitly not supported due to usability and security reasons".

I need to do authentication inside the app and don't want to redirect to some browser on the phone because of our application requirement.

Is there a way to do or any sample example to do the same.

I saw lots of applications is there in the play store which is authentication by Google, Facebook and not redirecting to the default browser. Instead of redirecting it opens popup window on the top of the current activity and does the authentication.

Example of "[Zomato Application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.application.zomato)"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that will depend on the browser, but it will be within your application:

Recently I had to do something like that, I needed to auth a comment system in my application that is done with webview, I also wanted auth to happen inside the application.

After much research I came to the conclusion that the simplest way to do this without abandoning the webview was to let the browser authenticate the user's access, and the solution for this authentication to occur "within my application" was to use the "Chrome Custom Tabs" that it allows to open a google chrome tab inside my application, with that i started to open the auth pages of the comments system inside the tabs of Chrome.

Unfortunately webview is inefficient in some cases, but this can be a solution for some people as it was for me, I hope it helps you.

To start the Chrome Tab when I added an "Intent" to shouldOverrideUrlLoading, below is an example of my code.

```html
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if  (url.contains("#comments")){
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
    builder.build().launchUrl(PostActivity.this, uri);
    return true;
    }
    else {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
    }
}
```

And in Gradle app:

```
implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0-alpha01'
```